# C# TLSharp delete user chat

Tags: c#, telegram

How to delete chat user C# TLSharp? Error chat id

```
var dialogs = await client.GetUserDialogsAsync(limit: 50) as TLDialogs;
var dialog = (dialogs.Dialogs[0]) as TLDialog;
var id= (dialog.Peer as TLPeerUser).UserId;
var deleteRequest = new TLRequestDeleteChatUser()
{  
   UserId = new TLInputUser() {
         UserId = id
   }
};
await client.SendRequestAsync<TLUpdates>(deleteRequest );
```

Comment: When you run the code above, what error do you get? what other details can you provide ?

Comment: error CHAT_ID_INVALID.

Comment: TLDialog does not contain chat_id, maybe not right TLMethod(TLRequestDeleteChatUser) use

Comment: `TLRequestDeleteChatUser` requires two variables, `ChatId` and  `UserId`. You are providing the `UserId` but not the `ChatId` for the `deleteRequest`

Comment: how to get chat_id?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this request? Delete a user from all the chats or specific chat, channel ?

Comment: In the telegram client it looks like this. https://prnt.sc/qn4v5v  This is just a dialogue with the user.

Comment: Dialogs.Chats will have the user, chat, channel etc info where Dialog (from dialogs) will only have specific info of that dialog item.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just testing to see how the user can be deleted, then this might help give you a better idea.

I dont want to make any assumptions but this is one of the ways to delete the first participant from first chat. I would recommend using Debugger to see how you can use Linq to filter out the chats and users that you are interested in removing.

```
    var dialogs = (TLDialogs)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync(limit: 50);

    TLChat chat = dialogs.Chats.OfType<TLChat>().FirstOrDefault();
    int userId = 0; // User ID To Delete

    var request = new TLRequestGetFullChat() { ChatId = chat.Id };
    var fullChat = await client.SendRequestAsync<TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLChatFull>(request);

    var participants = (fullChat.FullChat as TeleSharp.TL.TLChatFull).Participants as TLChatParticipants;
    var p = participants.Participants.FirstOrDefault();

    if (p is TLChatParticipant)
    {
        var participant = p as TLChatParticipant;
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{participant.UserId}");
        userId = participant.UserId;
    }
    else if (p is TLChatParticipantAdmin)
    {
        var participant = p as TLChatParticipantAdmin;
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{participant.UserId}**");
        userId = participant.UserId;
    }
    else if (p is TLChatParticipantCreator)
    {
        var participant = p as TLChatParticipantCreator;
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{participant.UserId}**");
        userId = participant.UserId;
    }

    var deleteRequest = new TLRequestDeleteChatUser()
    {
        ChatId = chat.Id,
        UserId = new TLInputUser()
        {
            UserId = userId
        }
    };
    await client.SendRequestAsync<TLUpdates>(deleteRequest);
```

View Sample code for looking up channels, participants, peers, chats etc from [here](https://github.com/ppanhoto78/TLSharpMod)

Comment: This dialogue is not present in Chats, it is only in Dialogs why that.  

 dialogs.Chats.OfType<TLChat>().FirstOrDefault();  this line return null

Comment: if you are getting a null thats because there is no chat for you to remove a user from

Comment: in the Telegram client  I see this dialog, but he is not in the dialogs.Chats. He is only in dialogs.Dialogs